# Remove middleware from store with Redux Toolkit

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a ReactNative app and I am trying to remove the middleware 'serializableStateInvariant' from my list of middleware. The page https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware lacks some information.

They indicate to configure the store with:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [thunk, immutableStateInvariant]
})
```

but there is no indication on how to import `thunk`, or `immutableStateInvariant`.

**How do I import them, so that I can set my middleware to `[thunk, immutableStateInvariant]`, without `serializableStateInvariant`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thunk is not re-exported, so you would need to omit the serializable check to achieve your desired result. The below would keep thunk/immutable in place.

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: false
  })
```

Comment: where is the getDefaultMiddleware function coming from?

Comment: getDefaultMiddleware is an export from RTK, but may be removed. I've updated the answer to use the callback version as that is now the recommended approach.